# Can we execute code inside setState apart from returning state object.?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-class-based-component

I have scenario where i have to set state for two of the properties and i need to get an updated response by passing previous state to a method. I think this approach is fine,

```
`updateResponse = (updatedRecord, status) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    userResponse: getUpdatedResponse(prevState.userResponse, updatedRecord, status),
    userCount: getUpdatedResponse(prevState.userResponse, updatedRecord, status).filter(record => record.status === 'NEW').length,
  }));
```

}`

To reduce multiple calls to getUpdatedResponse(), can i call the method getUpdatedResponse() only once, save its response to constant and then return an object inside setState?

```
updateResponse = (updatedRecord, status) => {
this.setState(prevState => {
  const updatedResponse = getUpdatedResponse(prevState.userResponse, updatedRecord, status);
  return {
    userResponse: updatedResponse,
    userCount: updatedResponse.filter(record => record.status === 'NEW').length,
  }
});
```

}